# Can I use a refrigerator that's been disconnected for a year?

Tags: electrical, refrigerator

I bought a new side by side refrigerator. Due to personal issues, we decided to use it after it spent one year in our new home, unplugged. Will any problems occur because of that?

Comment: I purchased a fridge in 2001, used it for 2 years, put it into storage for 10 years (with the door ajar), took it out of storage in 2013 and resumed using it. The only issue I had was that door the seal was dented where I have left something hanging over the door to keep it from closing. That resolved itself after a while. It's still working fine now.

Comment: Other than a good cleaning it should be fine.  Unless the frig manual says don't bleach it, I would bleach it or other heavy duty cleaning solution.

Answer (score 4):

If you empty out a fridge and unplug it, you will return to find a massive mold colony inside the fridge.  It is very important when taking a fridge out of service to block the door open and leave it that way for at least a month or two.

This allows the interior (and nooks and crannies and insulation which might be wet behind the interior plastic liner) to thoroughly dry out.  Assuming himidity is reasonably low at that point, you can then close the door and should be able to store it door closed.

Answer (score 0):

Any food in the fridge would have spoiled after a couple days, but other than that there's no problem leaving it unplugged for a long time.

Comment: As the above answer states, leaving it unplug can cause severe mold to grow, so I disagree with saying "there's no problem leaving it unplugged for a long time" as this isn't true.

Comment: @Edmund Reed, yes it is true as long as you leave the door open.

Comment: Then perhaps you should amend your answer to specify that the door should be left open, as it is not implied.